# How do I upload documents to the document folder of an iOS app for a debug run?

Tags: ios, debugging, file-upload

My use case is the following.

I want to debug an iOS application with a specific set of documents. The documents should be uploaded at each start of each debug run. I do not want to bundle the documents with the app.

Is there a way to set up Xcode 4 to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing with the simuator, then you could just write a script to copy whatever files you want to the documents directory in `/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<sdk_version>/Applications/<app-id>/Documents` each time to start your test.

Apple has some [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW4) which describes how to copy the "sandbox" into the Xcode organizer on to a certain device and app.